# API call counts if use Salesforce Workbench Developerforce

Tags: api, governorlimits, limits

I recently had issue with my org with exceeded request limit and I usually used developer console a lot but if I use `workbench.developerforce` will that still be count as API calls and account to my ORG?

https://workbench.developerforce.com

Comment: Yes.............But it will not be as heavy as IIRC it will not be polling rather it only does things when you click a button